# View formatting on Document Library in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, view, json-formatting, view-formatting

I'm looking to format the Site pages view using JSON Formatting. Is there a way to get the Published date field and also the page URL?

I see there is no column formatting on Name field on a library, but looking if there is a tweak to fetch the page url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the URL of Site page using `[$FileRef]`. This will be relative URL of page like:

```
sites/SiteName/SitePages/PageName.aspx
```

I was not able to find how to get the Published date field. But you can get the Created and Modified date using `[$Created]` and `[$Modified]` respectively.

You can use below JSON code on any field. It will show the current column value and on-click will redirect you respective to Site Page.

```
{   
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "attributes": {
        "href": "[$FileRef]"
    }
}
```

**References**:

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).

Comment: thanks for the response. FileRef works. I also needed File Name, not title. I was unable to get it through any references. So, created a workflow to update File name and also published dates to different fields. Was able to use them in the View Formatter.